Direction of triple cross product
I'm trying to comprehend why triplet given by $(\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) \times \vec{A}$ is orthogonal point in direction of $\vec{A}$?
I do understand that it's coplanar with vectors $\vec{A}, \vec{B}$ as soon as orthogonal to plane where both of them reside. It is orthogonal to vector $\vec{A}$. But I don't intuitively understand why it points in direction of vector $\vec{B}$, why not inverse direction?

@MishaLavrov yep thanks, elaborated a little bit more

$\vec{i}\times\vec{j}=\vec{k}$ and $\vec{k}\times\vec{i}=\vec{j}$ and you know that  $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$ is orthogonal to both vectors.

(I will denote vectors by bold notation and not vectors: $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, ...)
The cross product $\mathbf v\times\mathbf w$ is always orthogonal to $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$. So, $(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)\times\mathbf a$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf a\times \mathbf b$ and $\mathbf a$. (If you are confused, write $\mathbf c=\mathbf a\times\mathbf b$. Then, the triple product is $\mathbf c\times\mathbf a$, which is clearly orthogonal to $\mathbf a$.)
That answers the first question. For the second question, it doesn't always point in the direction of $\mathbf a$. Note that there is a formula
$$(\mathbf v\times\mathbf w)\times\mathbf u=(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf u)\mathbf w-(\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf u)\mathbf v$$
So,
$$(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)\times\mathbf a=(\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf a)\mathbf b-(\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b)\mathbf a$$
so, in general, it points in some direction in the plane of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$. You can also see that it points in the direction of $\mathbf b$, if $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are orthogonal ($\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b=0$), which makes geometric sense, since then $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf a\times\mathbf b$ are three mutually orthogonal directions in space.
Hope this helps. :)
